# Why does calling GetRgnBox on the result of GetClipRgn return a very different rect than GetClipRect?

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi

I've got an area on a `TCanvas` that has several sub-areas that need to be repainted, but other points that don't.  Since unnecessary painting can be expensive, I'm trying to only repaint what's needed by using [`GetClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144866(v=vs.85).aspx) on the canvas's handle and [checking if certain rects overlap the region.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162906(v=vs.85).aspx)

Unfortunately, now drawing is failing in bizarre ways.  So I called [`GetRgnBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144921(v=vs.85).aspx) on the region to get its bounding rect.  From the documentation, I would expect this to yield exactly the same rect as calling [`GetClipBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144865(v=vs.85).aspx) on the canvas's handle.  (Or simply retrieving its `ClipRect`, which calculates it that way.)  But instead, the two rects are bizarrely different.

The `ClipRect` property (the `GetClipBox` version) gives `(440, 231, 644, 427)`, which is what I expect.  But calling `GetRgnBox` on the region yields `(0, 0, 204, 196)`, which is completely wrong.  Does anyone have any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Comment: You say you're trying to optimise painting, but all these calls are to do with the current clipping region, not the update region, which is what `GetUpdateRect` gives you (or the `rcPaint` member of `PAINTSTRUCT`).

Comment: What does `GetViewportOrgEx` report?

Comment: Can you show the code. Perhaps there's some mistake in the code that you have not described above.

Comment: @Jonathan Mason is doing this in the context of a VCL framework event that is surfaced from the framework's handler for WM_PAINT. BeginPaint has already been called. So Mason has to infer the information using framework wrapped state.

Comment: Well, the two rects aren't that bizzarely differnt. They have exactly the same size, but one is offset by `(440, 231)`. So I assume that Sertac's answer point in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My assumption, what you have not told, is your Canvas has a device context that use a logical coordinate system transformation. This can happen, for instance, if it's the canvas of a `TGraphicControl`. Hence, the difference is one that of logical coordinates and device coordinates.

You can easily verify if this is the case by calling `GetWindowOrgEx`/`GetViewportOrgEx`.

You call `GetRgnBox` on a region retrieved by `GetClipRgn`. `GetClipRgn` retrieves a region that use device coordinates. This is mentioned in `SelectClipRgn`'s documentation, which `GetClipRgn`'s documentation states that the region it retrieves is identified with:

[`GetClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> An application-defined clipping region is a clipping region identified
>   by the **SelectClipRgn** function.

[`SelectClipRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162955%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The **SelectClipRgn** function assumes that the coordinates for a region
>   are specified in device units.

On the other hand, [`GetClipBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144865%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) uses logical space:

> **GetClipBox** returns logical coordinates based on the given device
>   context.

A very short example that demonstrates the difference on a `TPaintBox`. Put a PaintBox on a form with some offset (i.e. not at (0, 0)). The first `FillRect` call fills the paintbox's surface. This is the rectangle that `GetClipBox` returns, which use logical coordinates.

The second filled rectangle is identified with a call to `SelectClipRgn` passing the canvas's clipping rectangle. This rectangle does not honor the position of the paintbox itself, but aligned to the client origin of the window it's placed on. `GetClipRgn` would retrieve this region.

```
procedure TForm1.PaintBox1Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.Canvas.ClipRect);

  SelectClipRgn(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle,
      CreateRectRgnIndirect(PaintBox1.Canvas.ClipRect));
  PaintBox1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clYellow;
  PaintBox1.Canvas.FillRect(PaintBox1.Canvas.ClipRect);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this excellent answer.  I've managed to get it working now, based on this research. :)

Answer (score 0):

The description of GetClipRgn says the following:

> An application-defined clipping region is a clipping region identified
>   by the SelectClipRgn function. It is not a clipping region created
>   when the application calls the BeginPaint function.

So GetClipBox and GetClipRgn return two different things.